# Invite user without email + rails + devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, devise-invitable

I want to have a feature where I can invite any user using only their phone_number. I don't have the email address. When a user is being invited, an SMS is sent to the specified number and depending upon the contents of the reply(say, 'Y' or 'N') SMS from user, their account is confirmed/rejected. We plan to provide a link in the sms where in the user can click and enter the required details(email, name etc).

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)
2.3.0 :001 > u = User.invite!(phone_number: '1234567890')
=> #<User id: nil, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, phone_number: "1234567890", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invitations_count: 0>
2.3.0 :002 > u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fc91fcd4c00 @base=#<User id: nil, email: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, phone_number: "1234567890", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_created_at: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_type: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invitations_count: 0>, @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:email=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and i set example email for it and remove it later...

```
u = User.invite!(phone_number: '1234567890', email: 'example@abc.com', skip_invitation: true)
u.update(email: '')
```

Add this to user.rb:

```
def email_required?
  false
end
def email_changed?
  false
end
```